# paws preloader with the effect of movement and opacity down and up

Tags: jquery, css

[image]I am working on a pre loader with a project, my pre loader is consist on paws there are three paws on the position of bottom, right, and top I am thinking to show them in a circle

- paw one : opecity is 1;
- paw two : opecity is 0.5;
- paw two :opecity is 0.5;

is it possible with CSS3 key frames, if not then what is the solution.

Comment: how do you want them to animate? When you say show in a circle do you mean that you want them to rotate one on top of the other or trace a path so it looks like the animal is walking in a circle?

Comment: please check my image

Comment: give us access to the paws image and some code you have tried in a jsfiddle.